# How can I drag and drop objects into a Mapbox map from outside the map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, next.js, mapbox-gl-js

How can I create elements outside of a [Mapbox map object](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map) that can be dragged into it? For example, let's say I want to render a list of locations on a page. Each location is a React component with a custom marker or icon.

Next to this list of locations is a Mapbox map. The list of locations is not rendered inside the map. While I know it's possible to make these individual location components draggable, is it possible to drag and drop them into a Mapbox map and have it recognized as actual markers with latitude/longitude coordinates on the map? If so, how can I do this?

Here are the relevant source files in my code that I have tried:

**index.js**

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Plant from "../../components/Plant";

const MapboxMap = dynamic(() => import("../../components/MapboxGLMap"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const Blueprint = () => {
  const plants = useSelector((state) => state.plants);

  const showPlants = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {plants.map((plant) => (
          <Plant plant={plant} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="ui container centered grid blueprint">
        <div className="three wide column scrollable">
          <div className="ui link one cards">{showPlants()}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="twelve wide column">
          <MapboxMap />
        </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .scrollable {
          height: calc(100vh);
          overflow-x: auto;
        }
      `}</style>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Blueprint;
```

**Plant.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";

const ItemTypes = {
  PLANT: "plant",
};

const Plant = ({ plant }) => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: ItemTypes.PLANT },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  });
  return (
    <div
      ref={drag}
      style={{
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.1 : 1,
        cursor: "move",
      }}
      key={plant.id}
      className="card"
    >
      <div className="image">
        <img src="/white-image.png" />
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="center aligned">{plant.common_name}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Plant;
```

**MapboxGLMap.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import MapboxGeocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import MapboxDraw from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw";

const MAPBOX_TOKEN = "xxx";

const styles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
};

const MapboxGLMap = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [plant, setPlant] = useState(null);

  const mapContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = MAPBOX_TOKEN;
    const initializeMap = ({ setMap, mapContainer }) => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9", // stylesheet location
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5,
      });

      map.on("load", () => {
        setMap(map);
        map.resize();
      });

      map.on("click", (e) => {});

      map.addControl(
        new MapboxGeocoder({
          accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN,
          mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        })
      );

      const draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
          polygon: true,
          trash: true,
        },
      });
      map.addControl(draw);

      map.on("draw.create", (e) => {
        console.log("e =>", e);
        console.log("draw.getAll()", draw.getAll());
      });

      map.on("mousemove", (e) => {
        // console.log(e.point);
        setLng(e.lngLat.wrap().lng);
        setLat(e.lngLat.wrap().lat);
      });
    };

    if (!map) initializeMap({ setMap, mapContainer });
  }, [map]);

  return <div ref={(el) => (mapContainer.current = el)} style={styles} />;
};

export default MapboxGLMap;
```

Comment: You will have to post the code you have tried form your end

Comment: Hey. How did you manage to get the ```react-dnd``` working with Mapbox? I can see you have useDrag on your component, but how do you manage the drop action on the map itself?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, based on your related tags I imagine that you wanna drag and drop something like *pin* from outside to the map area. you use `reactjs` tags, it means you wanna do it by using ReactJS.

For this, you should install Mapbox by npm or yarn:

```
npm install mapbox-gl --save
```

or

```
yarn add mapbox-gl
```

Then you should wrap the Mapbox area in a drop zone. for this, you could use [`react-dropzone`](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone). install it by the following command:

```
npm install react-dropzone --save
```

or

```
yarn add react-dropzone
```

Add the following line to HTML template:

```html
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Then use it like below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN';

class MapComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lng: 5,
      lat: 34,
      zoom: 2,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });

    map.on('move', () => {
      this.setState({
        lng: map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4),
        lat: map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4),
        zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2),
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropzone>
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
          <section>
            <div {...getRootProps()}>
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
              <div
                ref={el => {
                  this.mapContainer = el;
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </section>
        )}
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
}
```

By using this method you can drop some images and got it and based on the drop position show it on the map.

**Note**: *reduce the file type catching to image file type like `jpg`/`png`*

Comment: Thanks. Will this allow them to drag an object on to specific point in the map?

Comment: @Wildcard, Actually, it is possible, but the specific point in the map should be in the view port.

Comment: Once it is dropped on to a specific point in the map, how can display a marker at that specific point?

Comment: I'm not sure the mapbox specifics, but in google maps any mouse event has a pixel location and a lat/long location. personally I really like using Typescript to discover these types of features, but I imagine you could find this in the mapbox docs -> https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapmouseevent

Comment: @Wildcard, you should show me some of your codes dude, but, after getting the position of _drop_ed mouse, got it and use it to position the icon as absolute CSS position. easy.

Comment: @AmerllicA added my code. Rather than using `react-dropzone`, I used `react-dnd` instead